# Laravel 8, installing React.js with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, tailwind-css

I spent a lot of time in HTML-only frontend, but now I'm using React with Laravel on the backend.

Laravel and React are installed correctly, no problems. But after I install Tailwind, I get an error in my terminal when running `npm run dev`.

Here are screenshots:
[image: app.blade image]

[image: app.js image]

[image: webpack.mix image]

[image: tailwind.config image]

[image: command image]

I followed this link: [tailwind website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel)

After that I follow this link also: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

When I run this command `npm run dev` I see an error on my terminal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read our [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Answer (score 0):

In the file webpack.mix.js remove or comment the line:

`.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`

Because you want to use a different css preprocessor.